# Android/Java - Draw text at the bottom of a bitmap

Tags: java, android, bitmap, kotlin, android-bitmap

I am trying to place white text at the bottom of a bitmap. Additionally, I would like to center the text horizontally, but that's optional.

```
val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
val paint = Paint()
paint.color = Color.WHITE
paint.textSize = 50f
canvas.drawText("Meme Text", 30f, bitmap.height - 50f, paint)
```

I assumed that because I set the y value of the text to `bitmap.height - 50`, the text would align with the bottom of the bitmap (since `textSize` is `50f`)

However, in reality, the text does not appear at the bottom of the image. How can I fix this?

Here is the corresponding Java code:

```
Bitmap bitmap = ... // Load your bitmap here
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
Paint paint = new Paint(); 
paint.setColor(Color.BLACK); 
paint.setTextSize(10); 
canvas.drawText("Some Text here", x, y, paint);
```

Update: I tried and that helped a small amount.

```
    val metrics = context.resources.displayMetrics

    canvas.drawText("Meme Text", 30f,canvas.height
            - paint.textSize/metrics.density, paint)
```

Comment: `paint.setTextSize(10f)` , here 10f doesn't mean height. To calculate height based on the textSize, you need to use `Paint.getTextBounds()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution turned out to be really simple. Change

`canvas.drawText("Meme Text", 30f, bitmap.height - 50f, paint)`
 to 
`canvas.drawText("Meme Text", 30f, bitmap.height, paint)`
.

It seems like `canvas.drawText` draws the text with its bottom aligned with the y-coordinate.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
// new antialised Paint
Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
// text color - #3D3D3D
paint.setColor(Color.rgb(110,110, 110));
// text size in pixels
paint.setTextSize((int) (12 * scale));
// text shadow
paint.setShadowLayer(1f, 0f, 1f, Color.DKGRAY);

// draw text to the Canvas center
Rect bounds = new Rect();
paint.getTextBounds(mText, 0, mText.length(), bounds);
int x = (bitmap.getWidth() - bounds.width())/6;
int y = (bitmap.getHeight() + bounds.height())/5;

canvas.drawText(mText, x * scale, y * scale, paint);
```

use this code hope it work as your requirements

Comment: What does the variable `scale` mean/how should I set it?

Comment: Resources resources = mContext.getResources();
            float scale = resources.getDisplayMetrics().density;